# How to implement prevent redirect feature using CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, http-redirect

Trying to build a website crawler that needs to have a feature to prevent following redirects.

Is using browser.Stop() or browser.StopLoad() the right approach for preventing redirects or is there a better approach to prevent following any requests with 3xx HTTP status code.